# open/edit all files of depot using p4 add/edit command

Tags: perforce

Is it possible to add all new files using `p4 add` command.

Actually I do not want to pass each file names or any wild chard pattern with `p4 add` command.

same question for p4 edit operation. Edit all files which are modified at client side.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at http://kb.perforce.com/UserTasks/WorkingDisconnected, in particular:

```
p4 diff -se //myclient/... | p4 -x - edit
find . -type f -print | p4 -x - add
```

If you are connected, then it's better to do p4 edit before editing files, as that allows other people to see that you are editing the files.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, this information is really needful for me and it solves my problem.

Comment: Hi Douglas, Please see my next perforce question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866373/how-to-perform-p4-submit-operation-without-passing-description-inside-the-p4-subm

Comment: Hi Douglas, please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866373/how-to-perform-p4-submit-operation-without-passing-description-inside-the-p4-subm , thanks in advance.